# Adding points to Voronoi Diagram in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, voronoi

I am using d3 to create a diagram to try and speed up a nearest nabour search within a function that plots points on a plane.

Is there a way to add points directly to the diagram so I can add the points within a while loop instead of re-drawing the entire voronoi?

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")

var distance = function(pa, pb) {
  var x = pa[0] - pb[0],
    y = pa[1] - pb[1]
  return Math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y))
}
var scatterCircle = function(point, radius, quantity, proximity, margin) {
  var x1 = point[0] - radius,
    y1 = point[1] - radius,
    inner = radius * margin,
    array = [
      [500, 500]
    ]
  //should be declaring diagram here and addings points below//
  while (array.length < quantity) {
    //constructing new diagram each loop to test function, needs add to diagram function//
    var newpoly = d3.voronoi()(array),
      x = x1 + (radius * 2 * Math.random()),
      y = y1 + (radius * 2 * Math.random()),
      ii = newpoly.find(x, y).index
    var d = distance(array[ii], [x, y]),
      e = distance([x, y], point)
    if (e < inner) {
      if (d > proximity) {
        array.push([x, y])
      }
    }
  }
  return array
}
var test = scatterCircle([500, 500], 500, 1500, 10, 0.9)
var o = 0
while (o < test.length) {
  svg.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", test[o][0])
    .attr("cy", test[o][1])
    .attr("r", 1)
  o++
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<svg width="1000" height="1000">
```

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert in d3.js but I will share what I found out. The implemented algorithm for Voronoi diagrams is [Fortune's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune's_algorithm). This is the classical algorithm to compute a Voronoi diagram. Inserting a new point is neither part of this algorithm nor of the function set [documented for d3.js](https://github.com/d3/d3-voronoi/blob/master/README.md#voronoi_extent). But you are correct, inserting one new site does not require to redraw the whole diagram in theory.

---

You use the Voronoi diagram for NNS (nearest neighbour search). You could also use a [2d-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) to accomplish NNS. There insertion and removal is easier. A quick search revealed two implementations in javascript: [kd-tree-javascript](https://github.com/ubilabs/kd-tree-javascript) and [kd-tree-js](https://github.com/sandfox/2d-tree-js).

Comment: Yeah, going to use d3's quad tree for nns for now. Thanks for response.